# Split string into sentences in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I'm trying to split a string into an array of a lines but it isn't working, this is what I've tried so far -

```
value = '<p>line1</p><p>line2</p><p>line3</p>';

var lines = value.split('/<p>|<\/p>/');
console.log(lines.length);

//expecting 3 but output is 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach could be to use native selectors (this implementation works with IE9+)

The idea is to hold your dom string in an actual html document body, and use `querySelectorAll` to fetch the paragraphs, transform the `NodeList` to an `Array` (the type returned by `querySelectorAll`). Then use the higher order function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build the array of lines you need.

This may seem overkill, but this is robust if some of your paragraphs happen to have extra attributes.

```
var sandbox = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
sandbox.body.innerHTML = '<p>line1</p><p>line2</p><p>line3</p>';

var paragraphs = Array.prototype.slice.call(sandbox.querySelectorAll('p'));
var lines = paragraphs.map(function (node) {
    return node.innerText;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Use it this way:

```js
value = '<p>line1</p><p>line2</p><p>line3</p>';

var lines = value.split('</p><p>');
console.log(lines.length);
```

Also, to remove the first and last `<p>` and `</p>`, use the RegEx you have. And for those who ask that:

```js
value = '<p>line1</p><p>line2</p><p>line3</p>';

value = value.replace(/^<p>|<\/p>$/g, "");

var lines = value.split('</p><p>');
console.log(lines.length);
console.log(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a Regex.

```
value = '<p>line1</p><p>line2</p><p>line3</p>';

var v = value.replace(new RegExp("<p>(.*?)<\/p>", "g"), '$1\n');
var lines = v.split("\n");
lines.splice(-1);
console.log(lines);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/goe14nkf/

This returns your lines correctly: `["line1", "line2", "line3"]`